# usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb, python-3

I am running Rasbperry pi and have the pyusb module installed. The printer is Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0fe6:811e Kontron (Industrial Computer Source / ICS Advent) Parallel Adapter, and it's idVendor and idProduct were found through the lsusb command (0fe6:811e).

Just like in the instructions, I enter:

```
from escpos.printer import Usb
p = Usb(0x0fe6, 0x811e)
```

Am getting these error

```
raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

Why i get this?
What i did wrong?
How do i solve this?